# Is there any open source software like Rammap?

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008, system, ram, metafile

I have a server which is running all the time, system makes meta file and saves then in memory, this increases the usage of my RAM so that i need to empty the system working set using the software [Rammap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx) which is a very hectic routine. I have to do this twice a day.
I want that there will be an application which automatically empty the system working set after the given period. After a very long and deep research I found nothing alike Rammap, even not a single library.

So any one knows about any way by using which we will be able to make an application to empty the system working set automatically.

Comment: On linux you might use the `mlock`  system call.

Comment: I would like to be able to do this kind of thing as well, but for Windows 7 Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

There is a utility to do this, as indicated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20585554/1671251).
You could use Windows Task Scheduler to have it run periodically.

Alternatively, if you have a specific set of files you'd like to remove from Windows' standby cache, you can open them with NtCreateFile (part of WDM) and call FlushFileBuffers to clear them from standby cache.
Here's what I did to test it with a small command-line application.  You'll need to include winternl.h and pull in ntdll.lib.  This can obviously be made more robust - it's a quick test app in this state.  (I tried using CreateFile instegad of NtCreateFile so that I wouldn't need the WDK, but haven't had luck with that route, yet.)

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   if (argc < 2)
   {
      _tprintf(TEXT("No filepath entered.  Full path required.\r\n"));
      return 0;
   }

   // Convert the "DOS" name to a Windows object model name so NtCreateFile can handle it below
   // MAX_FILE_PATH_LEN is just #define'd elsewhere to 1024
   TCHAR filePath[MAX_FILE_PATH_LEN] = { 0 };
   TCHAR deviceName[8] = { 0 };
   _tcsncpy_s(deviceName, 8, argv[1], 2);
   QueryDosDevice(deviceName, filePath, MAX_FILE_PATH_LEN - 1);
   _tcscat_s(filePath, MAX_FILE_PATH_LEN, &argv[1][2]);

   _tprintf(TEXT("Converted: \"%s\"\r\n       ==> \"%s\"\r\n"), argv[1], filePath);

   UNICODE_STRING usFilePath = { 0 };
#ifndef _UNICODE
   WCHAR filePath_W[MAX_FILE_PATH_LEN];
   size_t convCount = 0;
   mbstowcs_s(&convCount, filePath_W, MAX_FILE_PATH_LEN, filePath, MAX_FILE_PATH_LEN);
   usFilePath.Buffer = filePath_W;
#else
   usFilePath.Buffer = filePath;
#endif
   // Lengths specifically noted as bytes, not characters
   usFilePath.Length = wcslen(filePath) * sizeof(WCHAR);
   // Leaving one character for null term
   usFilePath.MaximumLength = (MAX_FILE_PATH_LEN - 1) * sizeof(WCHAR);

   OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES objAttrs;
   InitializeObjectAttributes(&objAttrs, &usFilePath, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE | OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE, NULL, NULL)

   IO_STATUS_BLOCK ioStatus_OpenFile = {0};
   HANDLE hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
   NTSTATUS statusCreateFile = NtCreateFile(&hFile, FILE_GENERIC_READ | FILE_GENERIC_WRITE, &objAttrs, &ioStatus_OpenFile, 0, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, FILE_OPEN, FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT | FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE, NULL, 0);
   if (NT_SUCCESS(statusCreateFile))
   {
      _tprintf(TEXT("Opened file successfully.\r\n"));

      IO_STATUS_BLOCK fileFlushStatus = { 0 };
      BOOL bFlushResult = FlushFileBuffers(hFile);
      _tprintf(TEXT("FlushFileBuffers returned %d; last error: %d\r\n"), bFlushResult, GetLastError());

      // Close the file
      statusCreateFile = NtClose(hFile);
      if (NT_SUCCESS(statusCreateFile))
         _tprintf(TEXT("File closed successfully.\r\n"));
      else
         _tprintf(TEXT("File close error: %08x\r\n"), statusCreateFile);
   }
   else
   {
      //WriteIoStatusResultLine is just a function to dump an IO_STATUS_BLOCK to output
      //WriteIoStatusResultLine(&ioStatus_OpenFile);
      _tprintf(TEXT("NtCreateFile error, Status=%08x\r\n"), statusCreateFile);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of people reported this issue over time. There are some pitfalls in the Windows caching algorithm and if you happen to run into them, the cache grows out of control until it hits 99%. In order to restore server performance the system working set has to be cleared and Windows never appears to do it on its own, particularly when you are dealing with huge file servers.
The tool is freeware and it's on our BackupChain website, free tools section. You set a RAM limit and that's all to it. The emptying is done automatically
Hope this helps!