# How to large memory blocks Windows 7

Tags: c++, memory-management, windows-7

I am trying to allocate a large block (5GB) of memory under Windows 7 Professional. I have a 64-bit machine and 16GB RAM and I'm using MS Visual Studio 10. For those of you who might ask why - its because I need to hold a 2-D raster representation of a map of reference numbers to polygon data, the maps can be up to 40,000 x 40,000 units. This has to go into RAM and fragmenting it into smaller blocks would be too expensive in runtimes.

So if I do this:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int t = INT_MAX;
    int * test = new int[t/6];
    delete test;
    return 0;
}
```

The call to new fails, but
`int * test = new int[t/7];` succeeds.

Investigating a bit more I found that the memory allocation is only using the memory which is designated as 'free' by the resource monitor. So when this is smaller than the allocation requested the allocation fails. The resource monitor tells me that (when I looked) I had ~5GB in use, ~10GB on standby, and a little over 1GB free.

As far as I understand it this should not happen. Surely if memory is requested it should be taken from the standby memory? If this is not the case then is there a way to reduce the amount of standby memory used by windows from inside C++?

The latter can be done outside C++ using RAMMap as I discovered from this post: [Clear the windows 7 standby memory programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841845/clear-the-windows-7-standby-memory-programmatically) but unfortunately there was no useful answer to the question of programatic clearing. Perhaps I am luckier in C++.

Of course the more likely scenario that I am just missing something obvious.

Thanks

Comment: Try building as x64 if you can, you're much liklier to find large contiguous blocks with a 64 bit address space (actually its less than 64 due to limitations but still much bigger than 32)

Comment: Is this compiled as 32- or 64-bit code? Because I can allocate 16GB on my Linux machine, in 64-bit mode (it has 16GB of RAM, so it will be swapping when it do that). Your test is below 2GB, which to me indicates that you are running 32-bit code.

Comment: Ahhh of course, missing something obvious was the answer. You are right its compiled as 32-bit. Compiling as 64-bit and the problem goes away. Or at least I guess until I hit the non-contiguous memory limit, which I have not done so far.
Thank you so much for saving me hours of trying to solve the problem the wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that when you allocate on the heap, that memory will have to be a contiguous block. If the memory is fragmented, no block big enough to hold the allocation may be awailable, even though the total of free memory is much larger than what you request.

Answer (score 1):

Memory fragmentation might be one of the issues: you *could* have that amount of memory free, but it is not continuous.

A better approach would be to allocate rather big chunks of memory (several megabytes) and link-list them. The probability that you will find space for such a chunk (and thus every of the chunks) is way higher than that you'll find continuous space for several gigabytes.

As of performance: as long as you are working on exactly one chunk, you will lose no speed as data remains in the CPU cache. If you switch often between two chunks (e.g. you swap items between them), you will get cache misses.

Anyways any workarounds like clearing the memory are like poker: you might get a chunk then or not. It depends on too many factors you can't control.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I made a stupid mistake and did not think to change to 64-bit compilation. But your advice is very relevant nonetheless. I have not hit this problem but it is surely only a matter of time before I do. I'll look at link-lists as a possible solution - thank you.